# sed is ignoring some matches

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace all matches of http to https using backreference:

example `test3.txt` file:

```
http://stronka.wpblog.internal http://stronka.wpblog.internal
abc
jdfgijdf dfijog http://stronka.wpblog.internal dfgtdgrtg http://stronka.wpblog.internal/ sfdgth http://stronka.wpblog.internal/dupa drgfthj
ghj gjerioghj fhjdf http://stronka.wpblog.internal/
```

and when I run sed against the `test3.txt` file:

`~# sed -r 's#http(://.*.wpblog.internal)#https\1#g' test3.txt`

```
https://stronka.wpblog.internal http://stronka.wpblog.internal
abc
jdfgijdf dfijog https://stronka.wpblog.internal dfgtdgrtg https://stronka.wpblog.internal/ sfdgth http://stronka.wpblog.internal/dupa drgfthj
ghj gjerioghj fhjdf https://stronka.wpblog.internal/
```

Line 1 second link remains unchanged, line 2 third link remains unchanged, I'm lost, how could I tell sed to replace everything that is matching?

Comment: Just use `sed 's#http://#https://#g'`

Comment: How about this: `sed 's/http:\/\//https:\/\//g'`

Comment: your `.*` is consuming the whole intermediary part of the string;  Change your pattern to: s#http(://.*.wpblog.internal)#\1# and it will be obvious .

Answer (score 2):

Because the `.*` wildcard is greedy, i.e. it will consume as much as possible of the line.

The simplest solution by far is to not use a wildcard at all; then `sed` does precisely what you expect on the simple input you provided.

```sh
sed 's#http://#https://#g' test3.txt
```

(Nothing in this regex needs anything except bog-standard 1968 regex, so the `-r` option - or its Linux equivalent `-E` - is not necessary or useful here.)

If for some reason you want a wildcard, use one which doesn't match across URL boundaries. In your example data, spaces seem to separate distinct URLs, so we can match greedily as many non-space characters as possible:

```sh
sed -r 's#http(://[^ ]*\.wpblog\.internal)#https\1#g' test3.txt
```

(Notice also how we use `\.` to match literal dots.)

Modern regex dialects like Perl's have non-greedy wildcards, but even then, it's better to use a regex which actually means what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
sed -r 's/\bhttp\b/https/g'
```

\b is used to set boundaries around "http"

Answer (score 0):

Based on the replies I've replaced the greedy wildcard `.*`:

`sed -E 's#http(://[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\.wpblog\.internal)#https\1#g'`

And it's working as it should now, thank you all!